# Is there a managed service for client certificate validation on Azure?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, client-certificates

I'm looking for a managed solution in Azure to do client certificate validation on TLS level. The app services support client certificates, but only as "header-forward" to your code. This makes it impossible to send a proper TLS handshake error. So, my question, is there any managed service in Azure which does client certificate validation and supports TLS level errors?

Comment: You can enable mutual auth on azure web apps. but then you need to access the client cert whenever you process the requests and validate it in the code.

Comment: Exactly, so not a solution to my question :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** out-of-the-box service in Azure to implement and verify a TLS handshake between client and server. Microsoft enforces that each application in Azure must implement it's own certificate verification code using libraries supported by the programming language.

[The managed service that *is* available is a key store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#create-a-free-certificate-preview), where private and public keys can be stored and used by apps.

I don't believe Microsoft would document something saying "we don't have X feature in Azure", therefore we can imply by the official documentation of how to configure TLS and verify certificates, that each app must implement it's TLS related functions:

[Use an SSL certificate in your code in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code)

> Your app code may act as a client and access an external service that
>   requires certificate authentication, or it may need to perform
>   cryptographic tasks.

This is followed by examples of how to perform TLS certificate verification in some common programming languages.