# Every certificate passed to the app service is valid

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, client-certificates, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I want to do certificate based authentication both in code and azure app service. So I tested the code and it works locally but for app service I want it to be bound to only certificates that I upload in tls settings. I read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/certificates#private-client-certificate) and followed every step but it does not work and every self signed certificate other than the one I uploaded is successfully passed this phase (app service tls). The point is that I want another phase of certificate authentication in app service tls before it even reaches the code.

Besides I'm using app service environment v3.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: There is  **no** service in Azure to implement and verify a TLS handshake between client and server.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729834/is-there-a-managed-service-for-client-certificate-validation-on-azure)

Comment: Then what is the reason for uploading private and public certificates in TLS settings?

Comment: it s a local cert store for you app to access, you can then check manually (in code) whatever you d like

Comment: The private key is a separate file that's used in the encryption/decryption of data sent between your server and the connecting clients. 
Public key it’s included as part of your SSL certificate, and works together with your private key to make sure that your data is encrypted, verified and not tampered with during transport.